# Zend 301 Redirects - some mysteriously not working?

Tags: php, zend-framework, redirect

I have a problem whereby some redirects are not working and some are. I am using a crude way of doing a redirect, which is catching the url in the `errorAction` of the `ErrorController` and then having a few if statements and then doing the redirects as follows:

```
 public function errorAction()
    {
        $request = basename($this->getRequest()->getRequestUri());
        $this->getHelper('redirector')->setCode(301);
        if ($request == 'rand.html')
            $this->_redirect('/services/currency/rand');
        if ($request == 'dollar.html')
            $this->_redirect('/services/currency/dollar');
        if ($request == 'zim-dollar-currency.html')
            $this->_redirect('/services/currency/zim');

        //About 20 of these If statements

        $errors = $this->_getParam('error_handler');

        //load appearance stuff

        if (!$errors) {
            $this->view->message = 'You have reached the error page';
            return;
        }

        switch ($errors->type) {
            case Zend_Controller_Plugin_ErrorHandler::EXCEPTION_NO_ROUTE:
            case Zend_Controller_Plugin_ErrorHandler::EXCEPTION_NO_CONTROLLER:
            case Zend_Controller_Plugin_ErrorHandler::EXCEPTION_NO_ACTION:
                // 404 error -- controller or action not found
                $this->getResponse()->setHttpResponseCode(404);
                $priority = Zend_Log::NOTICE;
                $this->view->message = 'Page not found';
                $this->view->headTitle()->prepend('Page Not Found');
                break;
            default:
                // application error
                $this->getResponse()->setHttpResponseCode(500);
                $priority = Zend_Log::CRIT;
                $this->view->message = 'Application error';
                $this->view->headTitle()->prepend('Application error');
                break;
        }

        $this->view->request = $errors->request;
    }
```

So, some will work and some won't, like: zim-dollar-currency...

Not sure why this is. I have even checked things like windows line endings etc. Nothing...

Comment: Have you done a `var_dump` of `$request` for the urls that do not work? Is it getting into this controller/action or bring processed somewhere else?

Comment: vardump gives: string(22) "rand.html", string(18) "zim.html" etc

Answer (score 0):

Try use [switch](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php) construction with default action